# QtCreator crashes X.org

Tags: graphic-drivers, system

Sometimes when a I run an app from QtCreator (version 3.4.2) the system freezes. I can move the mouse (it moves the cursor slowly and in small jumps) but I cannot do anything else. It's not even possible to switch to another TTY (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd>).

The SSH works because I can login from another computer. The top command shows high activity in `xorg` (100%) but if I try to kill it (`sudo killall xorg`) the terminal doesn't respond (don't give back the prompt).

Maybe it's a Qt problem but It start happening when I switched to elementary OS. Maybe any problem with the gpu drivers? I am using a intel integrated GPU (`lspci | grep VGA` returns: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)).

Comment: which is your video card model ? To get it run "lspci | grep VGA" on terminal.

Comment: What GPU are you using, could you run `lspci | grep VGA` in your terminal and add the output to your question please?

Comment: I have included the GPU model to the question (Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09))

Comment: Does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` provide any clues?

Comment: @elmato I don't see any problem in the log. I would check it when the x.org crashes. Yesterday I had not problems, I don't know exactly how to reproduce the failure. Any advice to kill/restart the xorg when it happens?

Comment: `sudo restart lightdm` will restart your xserver. Unfortunately it will also kill all child processes in the process (ie all your open gui applications).

Comment: I will try `sudo restart lightdm` but I think I have already tried it and the result is the terminal doesn't give me the prompt back. I have to close the ssh connection and open another one to have a prompt :(

Comment: Well it happened again... I could see in the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` this line: `(EE) [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing events are processed`.

Comment: `dmesg` might give a few more clues. I think you'll have more luck lodging a bug report over in the [xorg bugzilla](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=EQ%20overflowing.) than here.